InvalidOperationException: "Entity has one-to-one relationship. Soft Delete causes problems if you try to create entry again by same foreign key"
i send delete request for book on swagger but returns same error on above.i get this error for any entity with foreign key. there is one to many relation between book and foreign keys but i get one to one relationship error for some reason. here is book entity:
public class Book : Entity<Guid>
{
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    public BookStatus? Status { get; set; }
    public string? Language { get; set; }
    public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public Guid PublisherId { get; set; }
    public virtual Publisher? Publisher { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AuthorBook>? AuthorBooks { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryBook>? CategoryBooks { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<BookMember>? BookMembers { get; set; } 

}

i tried to add configuration for each entity, and set deleteBehaviour  to null and spesified relations with objects.Here is book configuration :

public class BookConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Book> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Books").HasKey(b => b.Id);

        builder.Property(b => b.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsRequired();
        builder.Property(b => b.ISBN).HasColumnName("ISBN");
        builder.Property(b => b.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        builder.Property(b => b.Pages).HasColumnName("Pages");
        builder.Property(b => b.Status).HasColumnName("Status");
        builder.Property(b => b.Language).HasColumnName("Language");
        builder.Property(b => b.UnitsInStock).HasColumnName("UnitsInStock");
        builder.Property(b => b.PublisherId).HasColumnName("PublisherId");
        builder.Property(b => b.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("CreatedDate").IsRequired();
        builder.Property(b => b.UpdatedDate).HasColumnName("UpdatedDate");
        builder.Property(b => b.DeletedDate).HasColumnName("DeletedDate");

        builder.HasQueryFilter(b => !b.DeletedDate.HasValue);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Publisher).WithMany(z => z.Books).HasForeignKey(x => x.PublisherId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.AuthorBooks);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.BookMembers);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.CategoryBooks);
  

    }
}





public class DeleteBookCommand : IRequest<DeletedBookResponse>//, ISecuredRequest, ICacheRemoverRequest, ILoggableRequest
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public string[] Roles => [Admin, Write, BooksOperationClaims.Delete];

    public bool BypassCache { get; }
    public string? CacheKey { get; }
    public string[]? CacheGroupKey => ["GetBooks"];

    public class DeleteBookCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<DeleteBookCommand, DeletedBookResponse>
    {
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly IBookRepository _bookRepository;
        private readonly BookBusinessRules _bookBusinessRules;

        public DeleteBookCommandHandler(IMapper mapper, IBookRepository bookRepository,
                                         BookBusinessRules bookBusinessRules)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
            _bookRepository = bookRepository;
            _bookBusinessRules = bookBusinessRules;
        }

        public async Task<DeletedBookResponse> Handle(DeleteBookCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Book? book = await _bookRepository.GetAsync(predicate: b => b.Id== request.Id , cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            await _bookBusinessRules.BookShouldExistWhenSelected(book);

            book!.DeletedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;


            await _bookRepository.DeleteAsync(book!);
           

            DeletedBookResponse response = _mapper.Map<DeletedBookResponse>(book);
            return response;
        }
    }
} 

Here is command section also.
Thank you in advance.
